# Unit testing decorators in Angular, decorating $log service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-decorator

While it is fairly easy to unit test `services/controllers` in angular it seems very tricky to test `decorators`.
Here is a basic scenario and an approach I am trying but failing to get any results:

I defined a separate module (used in the main app), that is decorating `$log` service.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('SpecialLogger', []);

  angular
    .module('SpecialLogger')
    .config(configureLogger);

  configureLogger.$inject = ['$provide'];
  function configureLogger($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$log', logDecorator);

    logDecorator.$inject = ['$delegate'];
    function logDecorator($delegate) {
      var errorFn = $delegate.error;
      $delegate.error = function(e) {
        /*global UglyGlobalFunction: true*/
        UglyGlobalFunction.notify(e);
        errorFn.apply(null, arguments);
      };

      return $delegate;
    }
  }
}());
```

Now comes a testing time and I am having a really hard time getting it working. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
(function() {
  describe('SpecialLogger module', function() {
    var loggerModule,
        mockLog;

    beforeEach(function() {
      UglyGlobalFunction = jasmine.createSpyObj('UglyGlobalFunctionMock', ['notify']);
      mockLog = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockLog', ['error']);
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
      loggerModule = angular.module('SpecialLogger');

      module(function($provide){
        $provide.value('$log', mockLog);
      });
    });

    it('should initialize the logger module', function() {
      expect(loggerModule).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should monkey patch native logger with additional UglyGlobalFunction call', function() {
      mockLog.error('test error');

      expect(mockLog.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test error');
      expect(UglyGlobalFunction.notify).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test error');
    });
  });
}());
```

After debugging for a while I have noticed that `SpecialLogger` config section is not even fired.. Any suggestions on how to properly test this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the module('SpecialLogger'); call in your beforeEach function.

You shouldn't need this part: `loggerModule = angular.module('JGM.Logger');`

Just include the module and inject the $log. Then check if your decorator function exists and behaves as expected.

Comment: yeah, I made a typo while 'obfuscating' my real application's code. The 'SpecialLogger' module is instantiated there, not `JGM.Logger` as before :) and still doesn't work as it should. Will try to do a plunker later today for this code.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I came up with a solution. I had to create and inject my  own mocked `$log` instance and only then I was able to check weather or not calling `error` function also triggers call to the global function I was decorating `$log` with.

The details can be found on a [blog post](http://nazargargol.com/extending-angularjs-log-service-or-better-way-to-monkey-patch-angular-services/) I wrote to explain this problem in detail. Plus I open sourced an anuglar module that makes use of this functionality available [here](https://github.com/Gargol/ng-honeybadger-logger)